# Add Checkbox List to UIAlertController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, uialertcontroller

I am working with the **UIAlertController**.

Right now I am able to list an item from the following code:

```
{
  UIAlertController *controller = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle: @"Beds"
                                                                            message: @""
                                                                     preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        [controller.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [controller.view setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

        for (int a=0;a<[bedsCount count];a++)
        {

            UIAlertAction *button = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle: [bedsCount objectAtIndex:a]
                                                             style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                           handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                                     {
                                         [bedSelectionText setTitle:[bedsCount objectAtIndex:a] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


                                     }];
            [controller addAction: button];
        }
```

I want to show list on button click in **UIAlertController** in format shown in below link:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pRXT.jpg

Comment: We can help you if you post the image even a link first, you can use http://imgur.com/ to upload the images. Because the first problem here is the actual UI you wanted, not in code 'cause your code is fine... And there's no checkbox in iOS but there are many other way to create what you want

Comment: @pepeng here is the link of the image http://imgur.com/bMu2GUc

Comment: Were you able to implement it? I sitll can't find how to just add a checkbox in UIAlertController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you had shown in the picture is complicated and cannot be implemented with a simple UIAlertController.

In order to replicate your screenshot what you need is

- Learn how to show a ViewController as a pop-up
- Add UITable to a ViewController
- Show items in a UITable
- Customize the UITable by adding custom cells
- In each of the custom cells add a button
- That button will have two kinds of images, one blank box and the other box with a check mark
- when user touches a table cell you need to change the button image corresponding to that table row so the user thinks they are checking or unchecking the box
- and lastly add a done button at the bottom to dismiss the viewcontroller

Google all these items for tutorials. As I said this is not a simple task as there is no out of the box check mark function in Xcode.

Comment: I will share the details what i did then let me know if i can make it better