# Checkbox in UIAlertController with actionsheet in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller, uialertsheet

I want to add the checkbox i.e uibutton and uilabel in one option in UIAlertAction
and only button in another UIAlertAction in UIAlertController.

Please help and advice how to achieve it.

```
 UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"My Alert"
            message:@"This is an action sheet." 
            preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet]; // 1
    UIAlertAction *firstAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"one"
            style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                NSLog(@"You pressed button one");
            }]; // 2
    UIAlertAction *secondAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"two"
            style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                NSLog(@"You pressed button two");
            }]; // 3

    [alert addAction:firstAction]; // 4
    [alert addAction:secondAction]; // 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this trick :

- Learn how to show a ViewController as a pop-up

  - Add UITable to a ViewController
  - Show items in a UITable
  - Customize the UITable by adding custom cells
  - In each of the custom cells add a button
  - That button will have two kinds of images, one blank box and the other box with a check mark
  - when user touches a table cell you need to change the button image corresponding to that table row so the user thinks they are checking or unchecking the box
  - and lastly add a done button at the bottom to dismiss the viewcontroller

Google all these items for tutorials. As I said this is not a simple task as there is no out of the box check mark function in Xcode.

From : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31941282/3901620

Comment: Instead of copying someone else's answer (even if you did post a link), simply vote to close the question as a duplicate.